# SQL single query issue

Tags: sql

I need to get the image names of four images from an image lookup table. This would not usually be an issue but all the four image `id`s are stored in the same row of a database table.  The table structure is as follows:

```
ITEMS_TBL
itemId
photo1
photo2
photo3
photo4 
etc

IMAGES_TBL
id
title
```

each photo column represents an `id` in the `images_tbl` table

Is it possible to get all the image titles from a s

Comment: Your question seems to be incomplete and truncated.

Comment: Why are ID'S stored in the same row? DataBase system is created on porpouse to avoid situazions like these

Comment: Is it possible to get all the image titles from a s??

Comment: Is this a one-letter hashing algorithm?

Comment: Redesign your database - it will make your life easier and also enable one to have an unlimited and unfixed number of photos per itemId.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as long as performance is not a top shot the following query would do the trick. Otherwise normalize your database schema.

```
select
  i.itemId,
  i.photo1,
  (select title from IMAGES_TBL where id = i.photo1) as photo1_title,
  i.photo2,
  (select title from IMAGES_TBL where id = i.photo2) as photo2_title,
  i.photo3,
  (select title from IMAGES_TBL where id = i.photo3) as photo3_title,
  i.photo4,
  (select title from IMAGES_TBL where id = i.photo4) as photo4_title,
  i.etc
from ITEMS_TBL i
```

Answer (score 1):

Until such time as you can redesign the database, create a view that shows this table as the link table you should have

```
CREATE VIEW ItemPhotos AS

select 
  i.itemId, 
  i.photo1 as photo,
  1 as position
from ITEMS_TBL i 

UNION ALL

select 
  i.itemId, 
  i.photo2 as photo,
  2 as position
from ITEMS_TBL i 

UNION ALL

select 
  i.itemId, 
  i.photo3 as photo,
  3 as position
from ITEMS_TBL i 

UNION ALL

select 
  i.itemId, 
  i.photo4 as photo,
  4 as position
from ITEMS_TBL i
```

This will give a view on this:

```
itemId, photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4
1       123     124     125     126
2       223     224     225     226
```

as this:

```
itemId, photo, position
1       123    1
1       124    2
1       125    3
1       126    4
2       223    1
2       224    2
2       225    3
2       226    4
```

From which it is easier to join with your other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
select img_photo1.title as photo1,
   img_photo2.title as photo2,
   img_photo3.title as photo3,
   img_photo4.title as photo4,
from
ITEMS_TBL items,
IMAGES_TBL img_photo1,
IMAGES_TBL img_photo2,
IMAGES_TBL img_photo3,
IMAGES_TBL img_photo4
where 
img_photo1.id = items.photo1
AND img_photo2.id = items.photo2
AND img_photo3.id = items.photo3
AND img_photo4.id = items.photo4
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this??

```
select P.itemId,I1.Title,I2.Title,I3.Title,I4.Title
from ITems_tbl P 
left join IMAGES_TBL I1 on P.Photo1= I1.ID
left join IMAGES_TBL I2 on P.Photo2= I2.ID
left join IMAGES_TBL I3 on P.Photo3= I3.ID
left join IMAGES_TBL I4 on P.Photo4= I4.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
i.itemId,
i.photo1,
i.photo2, 
i.photo3,
i.photo4,
MAX(CASE WHEN a.id = i.photo1 THEN a.title END) AS photo1_title,
MAX(CASE WHEN a.id = i.photo2 THEN a.title END) AS photo2_title,
MAX(CASE WHEN a.id = i.photo3 THEN a.title END) AS photo3_title,
MAX(CASE WHEN a.id = i.photo4 THEN a.title END) AS photo4_title

FROM ITEMS_TBL i
LEFT JOIN IMAGES_TBL a ON (a.id = i.photo1 OR a.id=i.photo2 OR a.id=i.photo3  
  OR a.id=i.photo4)
GROUP BY i.itemId,i.photo1,
i.photo2, 
i.photo3,
i.photo4
```

For mysql it's enough just to `GROUP BY i.itemID`